# Ruby open returning a string instead of a file?

Tags: ruby, file, open-uri

When trying to `open()` remote images, some return as `StringIO` and others return as `File`...how do I force the `File`?

```
data = open("http://graph.facebook.com/61700024/picture?type=square")
=> #<StringIO:0x007fd09b013948>

data = open("http://28.media.tumblr.com/avatar_7ef57cb42cb0_64.png")
=> #<StringIO:0x007fd098bf9490>

data = open("http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_279ec8ee3427_64.png")
=> #<File:/var/folders/_z/bb18gdw52ns0x5r8z9f2ncj40000gn/T/open-uri20120229-9190-mn52fu>
```

I'm using Paperclip to save remote images (which are stored in S3), so basically wanting to do:

```
user = User.new
user.avatar = open(url)
user.save
```

Comment: The question is: Why do you need that? Do you want to enforce writing those images to temporary files? You can easily do that yourself and have more control over where they are stored and when they are deleted.

Comment: @NiklasB. Just updated the post with a little bit of additional information.

Comment: What's the problem with that code? Does it give any errors? Paperclip should be able to handle any kind of stream, probably the problem is that it just can't find the basename of the image (which you can fix by adding a singleton method to the `StringIO` object).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Open-URI` has a `10KB` limit on `StringIO` objects, anything above that and it stores it as a temp file.

One way to get past this is by actually changing the constant that `Open-URI` takes for the limit of `StringIO` objects. You can do this by setting the constant to `0`;

```
OpenURI::Buffer.send :remove_const, 'StringMax' if OpenURI::Buffer.const_defined?('StringMax')
OpenURI::Buffer.const_set 'StringMax', 0
```

Add that to your initialiser and you should be good to go.

Comment: By the way, this will unnecessarily and globally force any code that uses `uri-open` to write the downloaded content to a file.

Comment: @NiklasB. Not if you reset `StringMax` to 10KB after doing whatever operation is needed. Not sure what the overhead of repeatedly unsetting/setting that each time the particular block of code is reached, but an option...

Comment: there's the chance that `open` returns an empty string. To account for that, I had to set `StringMax` to -1

Answer (score 2):

While steigers solution is a simple all around solution, some of us might be repelled by the "nasty hack" feeling of it and the way it changes behaviour globally. Including other gems and such that might benefit or depend on this feature of OpenURI. Ofc. you could also use the above approach and then when your done reset the constant back to it's original value and because of the GIL you might get away with that sort of nastiness as well (though be sure to stay away from jruby and threads then!).

Alternatively you could do something like this, which basically ensures that if you get a stream it's piped to a temp file:

```
def write_stream_to_a_temp_file(stream)
  ext = begin
    "."+MIME::Types[stream.meta["content-type"]].first.extensions.first
  rescue #In case meta data is not available
    #It seems sometimes the content-type is binary/octet-stream
    #In this case we should grab the original ext name.
    File.extname(stream.base_uri.path)
  end
  file = Tempfile.new ["temp", ext]
  begin
    file.binmode
    file.write stream.read
  ensure
    file.flush rescue nil
    file.close rescue nil
  end
  file
end

# and when you want to enforce that data must be a temp file then just...
data = write_stream_to_a_temp_file data unless data.is_a? Tempfile
```